# How to quickly sum elements in a given range in array?

Tags: python

I have trouble solving this problem:

> First line of input - N. N+1 is number of train stations.
>
> Second line of input - N integers c(i) - price of a ticket between stations i-1 and i.
>
> Third line of input - k - number of passengers.
>
> Next k lines: int a and int b (first and last station for each passenger).

Desired output: price of ticket for each client. I.E.

Input:

```
4
12 23 34 45
3
0 4
1 3
3 2
```

Output:

```
114
57
34
```

My code:

```
n = int(input())                                                                
prices = list(map(int, input().split()))                                        
x = int(input())                                                                

for i in range(x):                                                              
    a, b = sorted(map(int, input().split()))                                    
    print(sum(prices[a:b]))
```

I guess my solution is far from optimal as I get `Time Limit Exceeded` error.

Comment: `sum(range(a,b))` ?

Comment: @DeveshKumarSingh Sum(range(a,b)) does not sum elements from array in a given range, as far as I know

Comment: `sum(range(2,6)) =14` which is `2+3+4+5 = 14`

Comment: @DeveshKumarSingh I'm supposed to accumulate elements from array in a given range, i.e. 1 to 3 ---> 23+34 = 57

Comment: You can build a cumulative sum till each index in an array, and use that to find your range sums, e.g `[0, 12, 35, 69, 114]`

Comment: You're running out of time since your algorithm is O(N*k).  This can be done in O(N+k) as follows. Rather than compute sum(prices[a:b])), you should first create the accumulated sum array (say acc) which can be created in O(N).  Then sum(prices[a:b]) = acc[b] - acc[a] (which is O(1)) rather than O(N) using sum(...).

Comment: @DarrylG Oh yes! Thank you very much. One more thing that makes me fail is that if I create acc as list(accumulate(prices)) and then try to calculate acc[b] - acc[a] for i.e. a = 0 and b = 4 list (acc) index is out of range...

Comment: Solution description and Python Code for what I attempted to describe earlier. [Range sum queries without updates](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/range-sum-queries-without-updates/).  This is a classic problem with this solution.

Comment: @NotSoEasyAsUXpecteD--Since you had questions I provided the code to make it clear how to use the accumulated prices.  The trick was to prepend prices with zero when computing accumulation since there are N+1 stations, but prices only has N entries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution using accumulated array

```
def accum(a):
    " creates the accumulation of array a as input "
    b = [0] * (len(a) + 1)
    for i, v in enumerate(a):
      b[i+1] = b[i] + v

    return b

def price(acc, t):
  " Price using accumulated array "
  # t provides the start, stop points (e.g. [0, 4])
  mini, maxi = min(t), max(t)
  return acc[maxi] - acc[mini]
```

**Usage of above functions**

```
prices = [12, 23, 34, 45]

# create assumulation of prices
acc = accum(prices)

# Using your test cases
tests = [[0, 4], [1, 3], [3, 2]]
for t in tests:
  print(t, price(acc, t))
```

**Output**

```
[0, 4] 114
[1, 3] 57
[3, 2] 34
```